# Border on table row instead on td - missing td's

Tags: html, css, html-table, border

I have a table that is generated by PHP. I wanted to style the table a bit, so there is a `border-bottom` on every row.

I used `border-collapse: collapse;` so I don't have to apply the border to the `td`. I have reproduced my problem here:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zvpKBE

I would like to have every horizontal border as long as the row is. When I inspect my row, it's long enough, but the border is only applied to the td's in it.

Answer (score 1):

Your (td)header columns and data columns should be equal to have the border fully.  Like below

```
    <table>
      <tbody><tr>
        <td>This is an test</td>
        <td>Second field</td>
        <td>Third field</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
       <td>&nbsp;</td>
   <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
     <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
   <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
```

Comment: That's right. The `tr` itself has no visible borders, so you'll have to rely on the `td`s to show them. Fortunately for the OP, the table is generated by PHP, so they can easily calculate how many more `td`s they need to echo in each row.

Comment: Its quite hard, as almost all filled `td`'s have a rowspan of 2 or more, so its hard to see if the next row actually needs 3 or 4 td's. Was hoping there was a way to get the border right without having the right amount ot `td`'s.

Comment: it is always safe way to use table header column and data column equal.